# mathematical Analysis Course

Tags: real-analysis

I am PhD student in Mechanical Engineering and I need to take PhD qualify exam in Engineering Analysis. Therefore, I am looking for a suitable Analysis course. Can anyone suggest me a free online mathematical Analysis course that covers those following topics: 
Numerical Sequence and Series, Continuity, Differentiation, Mean Value Theorem, Closed, Bounded and Convex sets, Riemann-Stieltjes Integral, Sequence and series of functions

And the course follow the Book: The principles of Mathematical Analysis by W. Rudin

So basically I am looking for a free online analysis course which follow the above book. Thank you in Advance. Mehedi

Comment: just get baby Rudin and start doing problems, you're a PhD student you know how to learn, you don't need a course

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with [this](http://www.trillia.com/zakon-analysisI.html) or   [this](http://classicalrealanalysis.info/documents/TBB-AllChapters-Landscape.pdf), but no Riemann-Stieltjes integral in either.  For Riemann-Stieltjes integral treat it as a special topic that can be searched for separately, and quite good notes found for it.  If *free* is the crucial requirement here then there are good sources and you do not have to pay the big publishing companies big bucks to get adequate notes on these topics.